# How to deal with library dependency versions?

Tags: c#

I want to write a library that leverages functionality from e.g. JSON .NET. Let's say I use version 8.0 of JSON .NET. When I distribute my library, anyone who uses it will have to use the same version of JSON .NET, and it will conflict with any versions they are already using.

I could isolate the serialization part of my library into a separate NuGet package, but that would still be dependent on the particular version.

How can I build my library in such a way that it provides such serialization capabilities out of the box, and yet does not restrict the client code in terms of third party packages? Are there any existing patterns for this kind of thing?

Comment: You explicitly provide an acceptable range of versions that satisfy your library's constraint, or provide a minimum required version.  You never want to ship a NuGet package with a dependency on a single version, if at all possible.  And you certainly should not be bundling JSON.NET into your package.  You should list it as a dependency and allow the consumer to provide the needed dependency.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? If it is a dependency, then there will be a reference to it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your assumption is not exactly correct.  Other versions of dependencies *can* be used.  In .NET, we use [assembly unification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx) to accomplish this.  Essentially, the end user's config file can be written to say, "when the code needs version 8.0, it's okay to use 9.0".  And most of the time, newer code is written to be reverse compatible.

Ultimately, you can't stress out about it.  Comes with the territory.

Comment: Assembly redirects aren't exactly the safest bet. It's perfectly acceptable for libraries to change their API completely between major versions.